# Tetris CSS responsive, dynamic design

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

Let's say we have some block:

```
<div class="block"></div>
```

There are three sizes of `block`:

```
<div class="block b1x1"></div>
<div class="block b2x1"></div>
<div class="block b1x2"></div>
```

for example `b1x1` is `width:50px;height:50px;`, `b2x1` is `width:100px;height:50px;`

Now let's say we have plenty of block in our website and they are totally mixed up:

```
<div class="block b1x1"></div>
<div class="block b2x1"></div>
<div class="block b2x1"></div>
<div class="block b1x1"></div>
<div class="block b1x1"></div>
<div class="block b2x1"></div>
<div class="block b1x2"></div>
<div class="block b2x1"></div>
.. etc
```

But we want to keep them tidy, imagine you playing tetris using this blocks.

So two questions:

1. How to organize block structure using CSS/JS? Any known algorithm/jquery plugin/solution? Where to start?
2. What to do when visitor will change browser window size? (see the picture)
3. What about more sizes (for ex. 3x4 etc.)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about [jQuery Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)? It accomplishes what you would like with jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

Try the jquery plugin: `masonry`, do all you want http://masonry.desandro.com/